# Check if the operator is continous and if so find its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let's consider $$\mathcal{l}^{\infty}\ni \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \rightarrow \{\frac{1}{2^n}x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\mathcal{l^2}$$

Is it a continous operator and if so find its norm.

I guess I should estimate it using a proper inequality, but can't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$||F(\mathbf{x})||^2_2=\left| \sum_n 2^{-2n} x_n^2 \right| \le \sum_n 2^{-2n} |x_n|^2 \le \sum_n 2^{-2n} ||\mathbf{x}||^2_{\infty} = \frac 13||\mathbf{x}||^2_{\infty}$$

So your linear operator $F$ is bounded.

Considering $x_n=1$, you can conclude that $||F||=1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Shouldn't be there $2^{-2n}$ in the sum?

Comment: You are right! Now it should be correct.